# How do you keep a persistent display of optional keywords when autocompleting with Pydev in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, pydev

In Pydev I type this:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig
```

This will bring up Autocompletion in a window.  There are several optional keywords listed.  But as soon as I enter the parentheses, the Autocompletion window goes away and I can't see the keywords any more.  Is there a way to keep this information persistent?  If not, is there a way to output the Autocompletion to a Console window instead?

Comment: i found `def basicConfig(**kwargs):` => you want the tooltip displayed? or is there a list of optional keywords in you version of Python?

Comment: The popup contains a list of optional keywords.  I want this popup to be persistent until I'm finished with the final parentheses.  Since there haven't been any really useable answers, does anyone know how to contact the developers?

Comment: you can try to contact the blog owner from my answer for more help i guess..

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind typing a few extra keystrokes, you could copy the contents to the clipboard: tab, tab, Ctrl-A, Ctrl-C. Then you can Ctrl-V into an editor window somewhere.

Comment: While that does indeed make the info persistent, it's really not all that practical.  The whole point is that you want to keep the popup behaviour no matter where you are in the coding process.

Comment: Using the Practically Macro plugin, I suppose this possibly could be automated.

Answer (score 0):

there appears to be no setting for this. if you want to start reverse-engineering, this might be a good starting point:

http://xpomul.bloggles.info/2008/08/12/advanced-features-in-eclipse-popup-menus-take-2-the-new-api/

Answer (score -1):

to output autocompletion use ctrl+space